# Implementation of Generalized Hull-White interest rate model

Tags: hullwhite, curve-fitting

I am looking for implementation in R (or Matlab) of the Generalized Hull-White interest rate trinomial tree according to the following paper: [Interest Rate Trees: Extensions and Applications (2017)](http://www-2.rotman.utoronto.ca/~hull/downloadablepublications/TreeExtension.pdf)
.

Does anyone have any code that attempts to replicate the trinomial tree building procedure described in that paper? It is not ideal, but implementation of the classic Hull-White model would work too.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should give a look at this example: [Hull White Term Structure Simulations with QuantLib Python](http://gouthamanbalaraman.com/blog/hull-white-simulation-quantlib-python.html). I know that it's neither R or MATLAB, but the code you're looking for is already implemented.

Comment: Thank you Lisa for your advice, however the example provided simulates the HW short rate by generating different paths, which is quite a different thing from constructing a trinomial tree following the HW model. Being HW a popular model, I thought there may be some material out there (the Generalized HW is quite new instead, but never say never). Please let me know if you find anything. Thanks again.

Comment: Perhaps the trinomial tree, which in QuantLib is just an engine that takes as input short rate models, is exposed to Python, too. I'm just looking at the [constructor of TreeCallableFixedRateBondEngine](https://www.quantlib.org/reference/class_quant_lib_1_1_tree_callable_fixed_rate_bond_engine.html). That could be an implementation of the trinomial tree, even if C++.